# Vim Normal Background Changing Foreground Text Color

Tags: vim

I'm trying to standardize terminal colors in my `vim` theme and I came across some odd behavior about how Vim appears to handle foreground text color depending on background colors.

Consider this very simple `vim` theme:

```
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

set t_Co=256

highlight Normal ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=234 cterm=NONE
highlight PreProc ctermfg=197 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

It's not very pretty (as a simple example) but it looks like this:

[image]

If I then change one line setting `Normal` to `ctermbg=NONE` like so:

```
highlight Normal ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

I get something that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the background clearly changes (as expected), but the foreground color changes as well.

[image]
[image]

Why is changing this property in `vim` causing this behavior? How can I remove the background without changing the foreground colors?

I'm using the default terminal in OS X with 256 bit color enabled.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior is normal, expected, and explained in `:hi-normal-cterm`.

Basically, the value of the `background` option is used to define a bunch of default colors for different highlight groups and that option is redefined whenever you change the `Normal` highlight group.

To force a value for `background`, add this line to your colorscheme:

```
set background=dark
```

or:

```
set background=light
```

Also, there's no reason whatsoever to put `set t_Co=256` anywhere in any vim script.

Comment: By the way, I've written [an easy to use colorscheme template](https://gist.github.com/romainl/5cd2f4ec222805f49eca). Give it a try.